# Проблемы с передачей переменных методом post

Tags: php, html

Создал следующий файл post1.php, с такой формой для отправки:

```
<form action="post2.php" method="post" name="form1" target="_blank">

<p>Введите ваше имя:<br> <input name="name" type="text" size="20" /></p>
<p>Введите вашу фамилию:<br> <input name="lastname" type="text" size="20" /></p>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>

</form>
```

в другом файле - post2.php прописал вывод:

```
<?php

echo $_POST[$name];
echo "$lastname";

?>
```

но при реализации кода, ничего не происходит. Страница пост2 открывается в новом окне, но ни имени, ни фамилии не отображает. Где моя ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_POST['name']

Comment: Спасибо. ) Недоглядел... теперь все получилось.

Comment: Но есть еще один маленький вопрос - а почему не выводит при использовании стандартного вывода? Почему только через масив?

Comment: если я правильно понял , потому что register_globals off , что безопасно

Comment: и снова вопрос) читал разные мнения по поводу включать или отключать register_globals. так в чем же суть?

Comment: при on в скрипте будут автоматически создаваться переменные

Comment: С точки зрения безопасности лучше чтобы register_globals=off и обращаться напрямую к $_POST или $_GET